# How to create a Javascript video overlay with VAST VPAID?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, vast, advertisement-server

I am currently trying to learn the basics of VAST ("Video Ad Serving Template") and VPAID ("Video Player-Ad Interface Definition"). My goal is to show an overlay ("widget") over a video in a VAST/VPAID-enabled video player (like Flowplayer with Bigsool's DFP plugin or JWPlayer Advertising). The widget should consist of a DIV with HTML and enable interaction like mouse-over.

I am not looking for any scripting on the video player page as the widget should be delivered programmatically via a video ad server, so pure VAS and VPAID only.

There are many examples with Flash SWF files, but with Flash losing market share, I would like to work with plain Javascript only. Can you provide or hint me to an documented example with a working VAST and VPAID file?

Comment: I currently switch between a VAST Plugin and VPAID Plugin for VideoJS to handle both VAST (HTML5) and VPAID (Flash) ad content. The VPAID Plugin I wrote up and basically acts as an overlay to the video, so you can check that out if you want, it might help you figure out what to do.

https://github.com/Manbearpixel/videojs-vpaid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We currently implementing a plugin for videojs to handle VAST and VPAID (Flash/HTML).

https://github.com/MailOnline/videojs-vast-vpaid

If you are not interested in using videojs, but you want to use VPAID in another videoplayer you can use the individual modules to handle VPAID that the plugin is using:

VPAID HTML
https://github.com/MailOnline/VPAIDHTML5Client

VPAID Flash
https://github.com/MailOnline/VPAIDFLASHClient

we didn't split sadly the VAST one in independent module.